# Getting Holes in Orthomosaic using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, merge

I'm having some problem combining DEM rasters (tif-files) into one layer. I'm using the function "Mosaic to New Raster" in data management and the result is a combined DEM raster with holes in it.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Do the source rasters have nodata edges? Are your source rasters overlapping in their extents or nicely tiled?

Comment: If you use 'Identify' and click on a white area does it give a value in the expected range? I've had this issue too using mosaic to new raster. Turns out ArcMap was just displaying the data poorly and it was in fact all there. Try zooming in to a white area and see if it starts to display the data.